# No "HeaderBar" property of GTK3 in python

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have this simple window -

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Simplicity(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hb.props.show_close_button = True
        hb.props.title = "HeaderBar example"
        self.set_titlebar(hb)

        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

window = Simplicity()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

But when I run it, it gives me a error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simplicity.py", line 17, in <module>
    window = Simplicity()
  File "simplicity.py", line 10, in __init__
    hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 243, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'HeaderBar'
```

What is happening? I saw this example [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#stack-and-stackswitcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ provides [GtkHeaderBar since GTK 3.10](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html#gtk-header-bar-new). You're most likely using an older version of GTK 3. Check that the [unmodified example program](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#id5) runs on your machine.

Comment: the original doesn't run

Comment: Have you checked which version of GTK you're using?

Comment: I'm on GNOME 3.4.2, so I think 3.4? I dont know how to check

Comment: `from gi.repository import Gtk; print Gtk.MAJOR_VERSION, Gtk.MINOR_VERSION, Gtk.MICRO_VERSION`

Comment: For me I get 3 6 0. This is greater than 3.10, so why doesn't it work for me with the same error? Do I need to reinstall something?

Comment: How in the world is 3.6 greater than 3.10 ‽

Comment: if its a float number than yes...lmao